# Omniauth+facebook error when trying to cancel the popup

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, callback, omniauth

I am using omniauth-facebook gem in my rails application to allow user to sign_in/sign_up via facebook. Its working well. But my problem is when I click on cancel button I am getting following error

```
(facebook) Callback phase initiated.
(facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError


Started GET "/auth/facebook/callback?error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request." for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-18 11:42:36 +0530
```

Whats the matter? Adding **/auth/failure => 'pages#home'** is also not working.Please help

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the last section on https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/FAQ and see if that helps. It suggests adding

```
OmniAuth.config.on_failure = Proc.new { |env|
  OmniAuth::FailureEndpoint.new(env).redirect_to_failure
}
```

to your omniauth initializer. This worked for me locally, and then you just need to define your /auth/failure route & action.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem when debugging locally (localhost).
On a public url it worked, it probably needs FB to "see" you.

You can test on a public url or maybe use some king of tunnel ([localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/) is an ultra simple example).

HTH